# Skype - How to disable the comfort noise?

Tags: skype, noise

Is it possible to disable the Skype [comfort noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comfort_noise) ?

Comment: +1 for link to wikipedia article on comfort noise (I had no idea what comfort noise was :P)

Comment: Maybe they will fix this one of these years, when Skype crawls out of its permanent beta.

Comment: To anyone denying this: https://twitter.com/nicbravo/status/1038599239000096768 I’m waiting for a fix as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of Skype providing such comfort noise. And there is no setting to disable it.

--> Are you sure Skype isn't simply picking up ambient noise (computer's cooling fan, harddrive, etc.) either from your microphone or from the other party?

Steps you could take:

1. Adjust your microphone's sensitivity so that it doesn't hear background sounds but only starts listening when you speak.
2. Try to reduce the noise where you are skyping.
3. If you're using a laptop with a built-in microphone, try using an external microphone instead.
4. Ask the other party to do the same.

Comment: Dont work ... :(

Comment: @Peter Disable microphone on the other side and check. In my testings, with previous version, there was no comfort noise.

Comment: Skype does generate noise. There is noise which goes away when you stop and re-start a call, so it is not explained by ambient noise or analog hardware: it's a bad codec state.